# Javascript Cookie Not Working

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to do what it's mean to. The toggle function works fine just the cookie situation doesn't. When the page reloads, if even I refresh it after I've toggled the box closed, on refreshing the box doesn't re-close and just stays open.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this tells jquery to run the function below once the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#forumposts-icon").toggle(function(){

if($.cookie('forumpoststoggle') == "toggle"){ 

$("#forumposts-toggle").slideUp('slow');
  this.src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/header_toggle_down.png";
  $("#forumposts-toggle").parent('.widget-content-wrapper').animate({ 
'padding-top' : 0,
'padding-right' : 20,
'padding-bottom' : 0,
'padding-left' : 20,
  }, "slow");

 }

$("#forumposts-toggle").slideUp('slow');
this.src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/header_toggle_down.png";
$("#forumposts-toggle").parent('.widget-content-wrapper').animate({ 
'padding-top' : 0,
'padding-right' : 20,
'padding-bottom' : 0,
'padding-left' : 20,
}, "slow"); 
$.cookie('forumpoststoggle','toggle');
} , 

function() { 
$("#forumposts-toggle").slideDown('slow');
this.src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/header_toggle_up.png";
$("#forumposts-toggle").parent('.widget-content-wrapper').animate({ 
'padding-top' : 20,
'padding-right' : 20,
'padding-bottom' : 20,
'padding-left' : 20,
}, "slow");
$.cookie('forumpoststoggle','NULL');
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Got it working.

Think the problem was I had the close inside the button toggle! Silly me!

Working code for anyone interested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// this tells jquery to run the function below once the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#forumposts-icon").toggle(function(){

  $("#forumposts-toggle").slideUp('slow');
  this.src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/header_toggle_down.png";
  $("#forumposts-toggle").parent('.widget-content-wrapper').animate({ 
'padding-top' : 0,
'padding-right' : 20,
'padding-bottom' : 0,
'padding-left' : 20,
  }, "slow"); 
  $.cookie('forumpoststoggle','closed');
} , 

function() { 
$("#forumposts-toggle").slideDown('slow');
this.src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/header_toggle_up.png";
$("#forumposts-toggle").parent('.widget-content-wrapper').animate({ 
'padding-top' : 20,
'padding-right' : 20,
'padding-bottom' : 20,
'padding-left' : 20,
}, "slow");
$.cookie('forumpoststoggle','open');
});

var forumposts = $.cookie('forumpoststoggle');
 if (forumposts == 'closed') {

$("#forumposts-toggle").slideUp('slow');
this.src = "<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/images/header_toggle_down.png";
$("#forumposts-toggle").parent('.widget-content-wrapper').animate({ 
'padding-top' : 0,
'padding-right' : 20,
'padding-bottom' : 0,
'padding-left' : 20,
}, "slow");

 }

});
</script>
```